# Can we embed param in URL in Django app from url.py?

Tags: python, django

I want to embed param in URL by default like I have end point `abc.com/abc` with call type `GET` 
I call from postman like this `abc.com/abc?isActive=1` now I want Django to embed `key=1` in URL 
**Like This** 
`abc.com/abc?isActive=1&key=1` in url.py file

I now it looks no sense in it but I need this for some purpose

Answer (score 1):

In django you can't capture GET or POST parameters by default. From the [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against):

> The URLconf searches against the requested URL, as a normal Python string. This does not include GET or POST parameters, or the domain name.

What you can do in your view is to check the presence of the GET-parameter you want, like:

```py
# views.py
def my_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        my_param = request.GET.get('isActive', None)
        if my_param is not None:
            # do something
        else:
            # do something, e.g. exception
```